# Is the following statistically close to uniform? (and how does one prove such claims in general)

Tags: hash, provable-security, universal-hash, indistinguishability

For every $a \in \{0,1\}^n$ define:
$$h_a : \{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$$
$$ h_a(b)=\langle a,b \rangle$$

So $\{h_a\}_{a \in \{0,1\}^n}$ is known to be a universal hash function family.
This means that if we denote this family by $\mathbb{H}$, and the random uniform distribution over this family by $H$ then for any $k$-source $X$ in $\{0,1\}^n$:

$$ \Delta\bigg((H, H(X)),(H, U)\bigg)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}$$

where $U$ is the uniform distribution over $\{0,1\}$.

With this result, it seems intuitive to show that if we have, say $v$ uniform in $\{0, 1\}^n$ and $w$ uniform in $W\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$, then the distribution:

$$ v, \langle v, w \rangle $$

is statistically indistinguishable from random uniform as well. Am I right on this? And if so, how does one go about proving such a claim? (Cryptography is not my field so I'm lacking some knowledge on to prove such a claim).

Also, generally speaking - how does one prove that $v, b$ is statistically indistinguishable from random uniform, for a given random bit $b$?

Any guidance for both would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the definition of universal hash function family is: for every distinct $x_1, x_2 \in\{0,1\}^n$ we have $\Pr[h(x_1)=h(x_2)]\leq \frac{1}{2}$. There is no definition claiming that the output of hash function is indistinguishable from the uniform randomness.